# EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework) in C#

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-emf

I worked with [Eclipse EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) in the past

Now I am working in C# to create a tool that needs extensive modeling to capture its metadata, logic, persistance etc. What is the equivalent in C#?

The idea in EMF is that you define your model in UML, then generate the code. The generated code knows how to persist/load itself, expose its metadata, link to other EMF models etc.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an equavalent tool?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to chat with the guys working on EMF[EMF4Net](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/?project=emf4net)